# CE Cache not working with ExpressionEngine v2.8 Template Layouts - any workarounds?

Tags: ce-cache, template-layouts

Just starting to setup a new project, and using ExpressionEngine v2.8.x with its new Template Layouts functions. Problem is that if I have the CE Cache tags in the setup, and have set to dummy while I'm developing, it will break the Template {layout} tags.

Here's the template code with CE Cache that breaks:

```
{layout="_layouts/base" title="The Title"}

{exp:ce_cache:it id="page-home" tag="home" seconds="14400"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="site_content" limit="1"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {cf_content_body}

    {layout:set name="page_title"}
        {title}
    {/layout:set}
    {layout:set name="page_description"}
        {cf_content_summary}
    {/layout:set}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:ce_cache:it}
```

And here's the same code without CE Cache that does work:
    {layout="_layouts/base" title="The Title"}

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site_content" limit="1"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {cf_content_body}

    {layout:set name="page_title"}
        {title}
    {/layout:set}
    {layout:set name="page_description"}
        {cf_content_summary}
    {/layout:set}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If anyone has any kind of solution, I'm up for it or at the least some acknowledgement that it's a known problem and it's being worked on in the devotee thread that starting back in March 2014 (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewthread/12978).

Thanks
Brendan

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before as well. The issue is that the layout:set action doesnt occur when the cached content is retrieved, so the parent layout has no way to know what it's contents should be. Have you tried escaping the layout:set part from the cacheing? That may or may not work. Worst case, and the route that I ended up taking is to just use native tag cacheing when layout was being set. It's not ideal, but latest EE at least gives us a Redis driver for the native cache.

Answer (score 1):

This has also been asked on the official support forum here: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewthread/14051.

This comment: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewthread/14051#49482 also provides a way of caching the layouts although I'm pretty sure it won't address your layout:set issue.